# How to get time interval records in a range of two dates in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Am trying to get records in a range of two dates like between 2017-01-17 and 2017-01-18 and display the count of vehicle types available in each hour range, my query is not working out its results well since its passing the range.

my query looks like this:

```
select c.vtype, 
   ( select COUNT(vtype) from Availability where DATE_FORMAT(DateIn, '%H:%i') > '08:00' AND DATE_FORMAT(DateOut, '%H:%i') < '10:00' AND vtype =c.vtype ) as Eight,
   ( select COUNT(vtype) from Availability where DATE_FORMAT(DateIn, '%H:%i') > '10:00' AND DATE_FORMAT(DateOut, '%H:%i') < '12:00' AND vtype =c.vtype ) as Ten,
   ( select COUNT(vtype) from Availability where DATE_FORMAT(DateIn, '%H:%i') > '12:00' AND DATE_FORMAT(DateOut, '%H:%i') < '14:00' AND vtype =c.vtype ) as Twelve,
   ( select COUNT(vtype) from Availability where DATE_FORMAT(DateIn, '%H:%i') > '14:00' AND DATE_FORMAT(DateOut, '%H:%i') < '16:00' AND vtype =c.vtype ) as Tow,
   ( select COUNT(vtype) from Availability where DATE_FORMAT(DateIn, '%H:%i') > '16:00' AND DATE_FORMAT(DateOut, '%H:%i') < '00:00' AND vtype =c.vtype ) as Four

   from Availability AS c where c.costCente = '254' AND ('2017-01-17 00:00' BETWEEN c.DateIn AND c.DateOut) AND ('2017-01-18 23:59' BETWEEN c.DateIn AND c.DateOut)

   GROUP BY c.vtype ORDER BY c.vtype DESC
```

my table looks like this:

```
vtype           vmodel     costCente    department    DateIn                 DateOut
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MOTO BIKE       YBR125     254           403         2017-01-16 16:38   2017-01-25 08:54
MOTO BIKE       STARLX     254           408         2017-01-17 13:30   
PICK UP         D/CB       254           418         2017-01-17 10:58   
MOTO BIKE       MAX100R    254           418         2017-01-18 09:59   2017-01-19 07:59
MOTO BIKE       BOXER-BM   256           407         2017-01-26 08:09   2017-01-31 07:23
MOTO BIKE       MAX100R    254           403         2017-01-15 12:37   2017-01-15 04:37
TYT             HILUX      254           410         2017-01-17 08:39   2017-01-20 09:39
MOTO BIKE       MAX100R    254           403         2017-01-16 08:41   2017-01-31 09:41
SALOON          PATROL     254           403         2017-01-18 07:45   2017-01-30 07:45
PICK UP         D/CB       254           418         2017-01-17 13:58   
PICK UP         D/CB       254           418         2017-01-17 15:58
```

The result i hope to see is something like this to show the availability:

```
vtype       Eight    Ten        Twelve    Tow      Four
-------------------------------------------------------
MOTO BIKE     5       2           2        1        1
PICK UP       2       0           1        4        0
MOTO BIKE     0       2           2        0        0
MOTO BIKE     3       1           4        1        2
```

Comment: Provide the data as text table not as a image, image data is useless.and also post the data table of your expected result

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query